# Google Drive Api v3 does not allow deleting files of which I am the organizer of the shared drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Basically I have a program to do few things on a shared drive. There are around 15 people uploading audio files once a day simultaneously.
The account associated with the program is the owner of the shared drive where they upload the files.

The problem occurs when I tell the program to execute the function `drive.files().delete(fileId=id).execute()` to remove these audio files after downloading them but it raises `Permissions Error`.\

I tried to upload my own files and then try to remove them with the function and it does so very well.

So my conclusion is that I have to be owner of the files to deleting them, but in the Google Drive API wiki it says that a owner account of the shared drive where the files are can delete them too, so I'm very confused. "Permanently deletes a file owned by the user without moving it to the trash. If the file belongs to a shared drive the user must be an organizer on the parent.."
Link: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete?hl=en

I don't know what to try now

Comment: When someone uploads a file they are the owner even if its uploaded to a shared drive.  Check the permissions on the file and you will see who the owner is.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem.
Is there a way to change the ownership of the file they upload?
Becouse i only could be set to editor of the file but not give me ownership

Comment: They need to give you ownership only the owner can transfer it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the official document that you provided, `If the file belongs to a shared drive the user must be an organizer on the parent..`. You need to have a `Manager` permission to delete the files not owned by you using `Files.delete()`

[image]

---

### Note:

Don't forget to set `supportsAllDrives` to `true` when deleting files on your shared drive. `drive.files().delete(fileId=id, supportsAllDrives=true).execute()`

Comment: Tried this using the api explorer and I was able to delete files not owned by me in the shared drive that was owned by me

Comment: That was very useful, thanks you.
But i can't change the ownership of the file, maybe there is a funcion to do that?
Or how to give me the "Manager" permission without being the owner?

Comment: Go to your shared drive folder and select `view members` or `manage members` and see if the account that you used in calling the drive api has `manager` permission

Comment: You could also follow this reference materials: [Specific roles for shared drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-shareddrives#specific_roles_for_shared_drives) and [Create a permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing#create_a_permission)

Comment: This account owns the folder where the audio files are, but it is only the editor of the audio files, so I can't delete them.
Now i have a question, what do you mean by shared drive?
Because the main folder is into "My Drive" in the account that I am using and inside that folder are all the other folders and audios which I have shared to other users.
So is this a shared drive or not?
I never see "roles" like "organizer" and "file organizer". I just see Owner, Editor, Viewer and Commenter.

Comment: I thought you are using a shared drive as mentioned in your post `Basically I have a program to do few things on a shared drive`. But it seems what you actually did is sharing your drive folder.

Comment: I suggest that you use a `shared drive` instead of sharing a folder in your MyDrive for you to be able to delete files via drive api easily. [Setup Shared Drive](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310249?hl=en). Or else you need to be an owner of the file that you want to delete in your shared folder as mentioned by @DalmTo